# How to get decimal value from TextField and make calculations with it in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Im really new to objective c and I faced some problems with the Textfields and their values. I have two TextFields in my ViewController. With those TextFields Im trying to get the weight and height of the user and calculate their Body Mass index. I already wrote the code below in android and try to convert it to objective c .

```
valueWeight = Double.parseDouble(edit_txt_weight.getText().toString());
valueHeight = Double.parseDouble(edit_txt_height.getText().toString());
resulBMI = (valueWeight / (valueHeight * valueHeight)*10000);
txt_vki_resultText.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(resulBMI)+"");
```

My Questions are;

1. How do I get the values  from the Textfields (Keyboard type is Decimal Pad) and convert them to decimal numbers.
2. How to make the calculations in objective c, I get some problems when I get the values from Textfields with this code

`- (IBAction)btnCalculate:(id)sender {
NSString *weight = self.editTextKg.text;
NSString *height = self.editTextHeight.text;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)btnCalculate:(id)sender {

   double weight = [ self.editTextKg.text doubleValue] 

   double height = [ self.editTextHeight.text  doubleValue];

   double resulBMI = (valueWeight / (valueHeight * valueHeight)*10000);

   txt_vki_resultText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",resulBMI];
}
```

Comment: You really should be using an `NSNumberFormatter` to convert a `double` to a user presented string. And of course it should also be used for any user entered number string.